# Adding error bars to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a graph using ggplot from data I transformed into means with code:

I would like to know if there is anyway I can add error bars to this graph. I know I have to transform the data to have more summaries but not sure how to proceed. Tried to do it seperately for each column but could'nt make a graph from it. like this:

```
Temperature <- ddply(shlf, c("Location"), summarise,
                       N = length(temp),
                       mean.temp = mean(temp),
                       sd = sd(temp),
                       se = sd / sqrt(N))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please use `dput(means)` so that everyone can have your exact `data.frame` without having to copy it number by number (or to invent fake data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. This is based on `se` as provided in `Temperature` data:

```
means$upper = Temperature$mean.temp + Temperature$se
means$lower = Temperature$mean.temp - Temperature$se

ggplot(means, aes(x = temp,
                  y = Triconia,
                  color = Location)) +
   geom_point(size = 5.0) +
   geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = upper, xmax = lower))
```

Errorbar as a separate geom comes in distinct flavors: `geom_errorbar` is vertical and `geom_errorbarh` is horizontal; there are also things like `geom_crossbar`, `geom_pointrange` and the like. See `?geom_errorbar` for help and some examples on all of them.